# Ionic - Capacitor build

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, capacitor

I am switching my Ionic 3 application to use Capacitor. Is the a way to build the application for production using, as we did before, something like `--prod`?

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**:

In your case, run `ionic build --prod`, then `npx cap copy` and finally build the app for production in the native IDE.

**Detailed answer:**

This is how the [Capacitor app development workflow](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/workflow) works:

1. Build the web application
2. Run `npx cap copy`
3. Build the app in the native IDE

Building the web application happens completely separated from Capacitor. You could use any framework in the development process. What only matters is that the builded application is located in the `www` folder. Using Ionic, you can perform a production build by running `ionic build --prod`.

Afterwards, Capacitor comes to place and copies the web application in the native IDE projects, where you can perform an app build. Some platform-specific extra settings / steps are required to make the app production ready, but this again doesn't have to do with Capacitor.

Comment: `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` on ionic build.

Comment: @Xerri have a look at this Github issue. It might help you: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1036

Comment: When I launch the app on iOS, I get `Cannot find module "."` and a stack trace for vendor.js is shown. Updated app-scripts to 3.1.11 but the same error is still shown.

Answer (score 3):

Just an update:

In Ionic 4:

To do production build try this below command:

`npx ng build --aot=true --configuration="production"`

and do

`npx cap sync`

Hope it helped.

Comment: How about react apps?